# Unable to run karate tests - feature file not found

Tags: java, karate

I am getting error - no features or scenarios found.

Initially, I wrote my own feature but after repeated failures, I tried copying the entire `src/test/java` directory from the demo karate project generated using archetype and removed my own files, but what works there, fails in my own project.

[image]

Dependency in my pom which is also same as the demo project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
    <artifactId>karate-junit5</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I am running UsersRunner.java. Below is the error:

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: no features or scenarios found: [classpath:examples/users]
at com.intuit.karate.junit5.Karate.iterator(Karate.java:72)
```

Comment: hopefully someone else can help here, but in my opinion you have missed something from the archetype which only you can figure out. if maven and the archetype is too hard, you can use the VS code plugin (which bundles the karate runtime) and start running feature files: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=karatelabs.karate

Comment: Thank you Peter, I am only looking forward to work on Idea and its running as I explain below: 
I moved the `users.feature` directly into `java` directory. Now, I am able to run it with absolute path - `/users/xploreraj/repo/myProject/ftModule`, but not with "classpath:" which should be the way to introduce the tests in my project. Should the "classpath:" resolve to the path till ft module since the test runners are placed inside that module?

Comment: everything depends on how your project is set up. yes, normally the `src/test/java` folder should be the root of the `classpath:`, refer the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#classpath - if you still are stuck and need help, follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: I have fixed the issue and added the answer to the question too. Thank you once again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to inform Maven to point to `src/test/java` instead of defaulting to `src/test/resources` as outlined here: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#folder-structure

```
<build>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/java</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>        
    <plugins>
    ...
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And then `Karate.run("classpath:<path_to_feature_directory_or_file>")` will work properly.

I could only figure this out once I used absolute path to debug the issue. Hope it helps others.

Answer (score 0):

please refer to karate official documentation :
for does ho get a null pointer exception and exceptionInitialize or something like that: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate

this one dependencie does the job :

```
<dependencies>         
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
        <artifactId>karate-junit5</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>       
</dependencies>
```

i got this from : official documentation